# Mat-pagination does not direct me to new page afte adding row

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-pagination

I am trying to implement an inline row-adding to my table with pagination. To ensure the new row is visible, I'm directing the user to the last page with

```
this.dataSource.paginator.lastPage();
```

However, when there is just enough data to fill page(s) up to the limit of page size, e.g. 10,20,30 on page size 10, It will not direct me to the new page (with only the one row I just added). (At the same time, paginator show correct number of rows at the bottom and I can navigate to it manually)

Sure enough, I can see that `this.dataSource.paginator.length` shows outdated number (even though I have already done the

```
const data = this.dataSource.data;
data.push(log);
this.dataSource.data = data;
```

trick to push new row to the datasource)

I have tried some hacks that I've encountered across the Stackoverflow, like

```
    this.dataSource.paginator._changePageSize(this.dataSource.paginator.pageSize);
```

Or try to force navigate to next page with

```
this.dataSource.paginator.nextPage();
```

**My component**

```
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
  }
  request(params?) {
    this.logApi.getList(params)
      .toPromise()
      .then(data => {
        this.dataSource.data = data;
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }

  addLog() {
const log = new Log();
log.assignee = '';
log.timeSpentTotal = 0;
this.checkRowValid();
const data = this.dataSource.data;
data.push(log);
this.dataSource.data = data;
this.dataSource.paginator.lastPage();
if (this.dataSource.paginator.hasNextPage()) {
 this.dataSource.paginator.nextPage();
}
```

}

**HTML**

```
<nb-card>
  <nb-card-header>
    Logs <button nbButton hero status="success" (click)="addLog()" size="tiny" [disabled]="rowAddMode || rowEditMode">Add new</button>
  </nb-card-header>
  <table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort mat-table [ngClass]="'mat-elevation-z8'" multiTemplateDataRows>
    /* ... */
  </table>
  <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[10]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
```

Needless to say, I have stripped some code for length

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post all of your component code that relates to adding the row and updating the data source?

Comment: Edited the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manually updating the paginator length seems to work.

```js
  addLog() {
    const log = new Log();
    log.assignee = "";
    log.timeSpentTotal = 0;
    this.checkRowValid();
    const data = this.dataSource.data;
    data.push(log);
    this.dataSource.data = data; 
    this.paginator.length = data.length; //  Add this
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator; //  Add this
    this.dataSource.paginator.lastPage();
  }
```

[Stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-biepp3?file=src/app/table-pagination-example.ts), I had to use different data, of course.

Comment: Thanks, this indeed works